# Angular 2: How to load data from service before creating model based formgroup

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I have a page in Angular 2 webpack where I have such a form group in my component:

```
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
    date_of_visit: ['', [<any>Validators.required]]
});
```

At the moment i run that code in `ngOnInit()` and run it again after a callback function is called when my data is ready through my service:

```
setFormsData(d) {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        date_of_visit: [d.date_of_visit, [<any>Validators.required]]
    });
}
```

`setFormsData` is called when my data has been retrieved from the database. So at the moment I initialize forms in `ngOnInit` and refill is with new data and have all my validators etc on both.

**QUESTION:**
What is the correct way to iniliaze form with data, and how do i load my data before my page so that I don't have to run the same code for my forms twice?

**Source screen:**

https://gyazo.com/21347a7876e9d8289f5e3e72191baaeb
https://gyazo.com/cdf80721d12c531f7c0d9aa420f31691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets initialize form group in ngOnInit with empty forms. And here after initializing form send an async request to server, where in subscription you can call updateValueAndValidity().

```
ngOnInit() {
    // init form here with validators etc...

    someService.getData().subscribe(
       response => {
           this.data = response.json();
           this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity();
       }
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how I am supposed to set my data into my forms before calling updateValueAndValidity?

Comment: do you use data-binding? this.data which i wrote though that is rendered in template. For example in your template is `<input [(ngModel)]="data.visited" formControlName="date_of_visit">`. After awaiting data you set it in subscribe callback `this.data = response.json()` and the template will be changed. The subscribe method does request asynchronously and your callback will be executed only when you will receive response from server. The main reason to initialize form before sending request is because it executes async and view will be rendered before the request will be obtained.

Comment: And you can't load data before your page. But you can hide the form until is not received answer from server `reposne => {this.data = response.json(); this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity(); this.showForm = true;}`.

Comment: I currently don't use ngModel for databinding. I have a question to your solution though. if I used "data.visited" for the ng, it will change the data in the input field, but what about before there is any data in the variable "data", and that point it does not include. in my code i added a field "data: any; and i do this to set the data "this.data = response.json();" but the page crashed because: "cannot read property 'visited' of undefined"

Comment: The data is set correctly. If I removed the ngmodel on my input field and console.log the data after the subscribe callback is called I can see the data is there.

Comment: If you need more help, please provide the source code, cause i'm a little bit stuck.

Comment: I added an edit to the post with a screenshot of the relevant code in my component and html for one of the input fields. If you want the code in any other way let me know. I hope you can help me out, cuz I'm really stuck on what to do in this situation! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130524/discussion-between-unsafeptr-and-vanquiza).

Comment: is this resolved?i have similar issue, I am using current angular 4

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Use the setValue method on the form.

```
setFormsData(d) {
   this.myForm.setValue(d);
}
```